# Python Column Generation with AVERAGEIF for LARGER DATASET

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, average

I've poured over StackOverflow got part of the way there with groupby in my last question, but groupby can't seem to accomplish what I'm looking for. I have data tables with the unique letter and time combinations, and I'm trying to get the "averageif" of those values into the second table, BUT NOT ALL OF THE VALUES.

```
Letter  Time   Value          Time      A2       B3
A1      1:00    7.97          1:00     3.16     4.32  
A1      2:00    3.56          2:00     5.06     6.76
A2      1:00    3.16          
A2      2:00    9.09           
A2      2:00    0.64           
A2      2:00    5.44           
A3      1:00    1.53
B1      2:00    4.55
B1      3:00    7.36
B2      1:00    3.81
B2      2:00    7.30
B3      1:00    4.34
B3      1:00    4.30
B3      2:00    4.61
B3      2:00    8.91
```

I can't figure out how to write something that can intelligently calculate only the averages, I'm, looking based on the two-column analysis. I have all the code to pull this data in from a CSV, generate the unique values, etc. but it doesn't seem relevant. Thanks for any advice, I just can't get past this step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your desired rows with `isin` and just call `groupby` + `mean`. Make a final unstack call to reshape your output.

```
df[df.Letter.isin(['A2', 'B3'])]\
     .groupby(['Letter', 'Time']).Value.mean().unstack().T

Letter        A2    B3
Time                  
1:00    3.160000  4.32
2:00    5.056667  6.76
```

Comment: ColdSpeed, YOU'RE ABSOLUTELY FREEZING AND EXTREMELY FAST!!! This saved me a lot of time, plus I learned something, thanks very much for the help -